# How to put a Property List in the Documents folder of my app when app is shipped?

Tags: iphone, nsdocument, property-list

I have several tableviews in my app and the data source for each tableview is a property list. Currently I have the propertylists saved in the application bundle. However, thats only because I created them in XCode and they are automatically saved in the documents folder.  This is fine as when the app ships, thats where they need to be.

However, I would like to put a copy of the property lists in the documents folder of my app as well when it ships. How can I do that? I mean Can I program XCode to save the pLists I create manually to save in the documents folder of my app? Or how does that work? Basically to summarize, I would like to put a copy of the propertylist each in the application bundle and the documents folder

I appreciate any help anyone provides.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You would have to copy the file over when the app is first run, either by detecting that the file doesn't exist or by checking a flag in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick answer. Can I ask then a few more follow up questions?. Assume that I keep the file in the bundle and don't create a copy of the file in the documents folder. Thus each time the app runs it will pull the file from the bundle as it wont find it in the documents folder. However, I will only put the file in the documents folder when I have a new version of the property list, How do I put the file in the documents folder remotely, from my own server? I mean Ill have to program the app to check a version # from a URL everytime it starts if the #s dont match, then download

Comment: You can't put the file in the documents folder from your server, you'll have to have the app poll your server periodically and download the new version when necessary.

Comment: So when the app downloads the new version, how can I program that to go in the documents folder, or is that done automatically?

Comment: If you have the plist data loaded into an NSDictionary, NSArray, or NSData, you can use `writeToFile:atomically:` to write it out. You can get the location of the documents directory with `NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];`.